# list of methods for python shell?

Tags: python, shell, interactive

You'd have already found out by my usage of terminology that I'm a python n00b.

straight forward question:

How can i see a list of methods for a particular object in an interactive python shell like i can in ruby (you can do that in ruby irb with a '.methods' after the object)?

Comment: Title is misleading: this is not a request for a list of methods of the shell, but, in the interactive Python shell, how to get a list of methods for an object. (Equivalently, in a Python program in general).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Existing answers do a good job of showing you how to get the ATTRIBUTES of an object, but do not precisely answer the question you posed -- how to get the METHODS of an object. Python objects have a unified namespace (differently from Ruby, where methods and attributes use different namespaces).  Consider for example:

```
>>> class X(object):
...   @classmethod
...   def clame(cls): pass
...   @staticmethod
...   def stame(): pass
...   def meth(self): pass
...   def __init__(self):
...     self.lam = lambda: None
...     self.val = 23
... 
>>> x = X()
>>> dir(x)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__',
 '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__',
 '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__',
 'clame', 'lam', 'meth', 'stame', 'val']
```

((output split for readability)).

As you see, this is giving you the names of all attributes -- including plenty of special methods that are just inherited from `object`, special data attributes such as `__class__`, `__dict__` and `__doc__`, per-instance data attributes (`val`), per-instance executable attributes (`lam`), as well as actual methods.

If and when you need to be more selective, try:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> [n for n, v in inspect.getmembers(x, inspect.ismethod)]
['__init__', 'clame', 'meth']
```

Standard library module `inspect` is the best way to do introspection in Python: it builds on top of the built-in introspection hooks (such as `dir` and more advanced ones) to offer you useful, rich, and simple introspection services. Here, for example, you see that only instance and class methods specifically designed by this class are shown -- not static methods, not instance attributes whether callable or not, not special methods inherited from `object`. If your selectivity needs are slightly different, it's easy to build your own tweaked version of `ismethod` and pass it as the second argument of `getmembers`, to tailor the results to your precise, exact needs.

Answer (score 10):

`dir( object )`

will give you the list.

for instance:

```
a = 2
dir( a )
```

will list off all the methods you can call for an integer.

Answer (score 6):

Its simple do this for any object you have created

```
dir(object)
```

it will return a list of all the attributes of the object.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> help(my_object)
```

Comment: This is not actually correct. help is used to display the docstring documentation for a method. e.g. help(string.upper). dir(obj) is what is required.

Comment: Correct. If something like .methods in Ruby is required, dir(...) is the correct answer.

Comment: For interactive use (the OP's use case), this is actually the best approach. The help system will print out the documentation for `my_object`, including a list of all advertised methods (whether or not they have their own docstring). It won't show methods with names that start with `_`, but that's usually ok since such methods are meant for the internal use of the class.

Answer (score 4):

Python supports tab completion as well. I prefer my python prompt clean (so no thanks to IPython), but with tab completion.

Setup in .bashrc or similar:

```
PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc
```

Put this in .pythonrc:

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print ("Module readline not available.")
else:
    print ("Enabling tab completion")
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
```

It will print "Enabling tab completion" each time the python prompt starts up, because it's better to be explicit. This won't interfere with execution of python scripts and programs.

---

Example:

```
>>> lst = []
>>> lst.
lst.__add__(           lst.__iadd__(          lst.__setattr__(
lst.__class__(         lst.__imul__(          lst.__setitem__(
lst.__contains__(      lst.__init__(          lst.__setslice__(
lst.__delattr__(       lst.__iter__(          lst.__sizeof__(
lst.__delitem__(       lst.__le__(            lst.__str__(
lst.__delslice__(      lst.__len__(           lst.__subclasshook__(
lst.__doc__            lst.__lt__(            lst.append(
lst.__eq__(            lst.__mul__(           lst.count(
lst.__format__(        lst.__ne__(            lst.extend(
lst.__ge__(            lst.__new__(           lst.index(
lst.__getattribute__(  lst.__reduce__(        lst.insert(
lst.__getitem__(       lst.__reduce_ex__(     lst.pop(
lst.__getslice__(      lst.__repr__(          lst.remove(
lst.__gt__(            lst.__reversed__(      lst.reverse(
lst.__hash__           lst.__rmul__(          lst.sort(
```

Comment: +1 tab completion makes the standard prompt much more pleasant; I don't know why it's not on by default. You can also put the code in your sitecustomize.py if you like to avoid having to set a STARTUP (although in this case you'd leave out the prints). Note that Windows and Mac users won't have readline by default and will need to download an appropriate module such as pyreadline (Win) or readline.py (Mac).

Comment: With sitecustomize.py it might influence python applications, while PYTHONSTARTUP in .bashrc makes so that it will only import readline when started from the commandline. This is if I understand sitecustomize.py correctly.

Comment: It will, yes, if they use [raw_]input(). This is generally more likely to be a useful thing than to mess anything up, though.

Answer (score 3):

For an enhanced version of `dir()` check out `see()`!

```
>>> test = [1,2,3]
>>> see(test)
    []    in    +    +=    *    *=    <    <=    ==    !=    >    >=    hash()
    help()    iter()    len()    repr()    reversed()    str()    .append()
    .count()    .extend()    .index()    .insert()    .pop()    .remove()
    .reverse()    .sort()
```

You can get it here:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/see/0.5.4 (packaged version)
- http://inky.github.com/see/ (home page)
- http://github.com/inky/see/tree/master (source)

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
dir(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned [`dir`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#dir). Let me make an remark of caution: Python objects may have a [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__getattr__#object.__getattr__) method defined which is called when one attempts to call an undefined method on said object. Obviously `dir` does not list all those (infinitely many) method names. Some libraries make explicit use of this feature, e.g. [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) (Python Lex-Yacc).

Example:

```
>>> class Test:
...     def __getattr__(self, name):
...         return 'foo <%s>' % name
...
>>> t = Test()
>>> t.bar
'foo <bar>'
>>> 'bar' in dir(t)
False
```

Comment: ...and carrying on the Ruby analogy from the question, a Ruby class may have overridden method_missing which is called when there is an attempt to call an undefined method and of course obj.methods can't know about method names that are intended to be handled by method_missing.

Comment: @mikej: thanks! I have no Ruby experience, but when I wrote my answer it did cross my mind that Ruby should have equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only methods, then

```
def methods(obj):
    return [attr for attr in dir(obj) if callable(getattr(obj, attr))]
```

But do try out IPython, it has tab completion for object attributes, so typing `obj.<tab>` shows you a list of available attributes on that object.

Comment: idle supports tab-completion as well